# Populate fields using dropdown list

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a Dropdown list that is populated by MySQL database using the following code

```
<?php

                    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '@', '')
                    or die ('Cannot connect to db');

                    $result = $conn->query("select name, surname FROM clients");
                    echo "<html>";
                    echo "<body>";
                    echo "<select name='client_name' id='client'>";

                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                        unset($msisdn, $contract_type, $provider);
                        $name = $row['name'];
                        $surname = $row['surname'];
                        echo '<option value="'.$name.'_'.$surname.'">'.$name.' '.$surname.'</option>';
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                    echo "</body>";
                    echo "</html>";
                    ?>
```

I want to populate different fields with information related to the result in the drop down list.

```
<input type="text" name="address">
<input type="text" name="tel">
<input type="text" name="id_nr">

$('#client').change(function() {
    selectedOption = $('option:selected', this);
    $('input[name=address]').val( selectedOption.data('address') );
    $('input[name=tel]').val( selectedOption.data('tel') );
    $('input[name=id_nr]').val( selectedOption.data('id_nr') );
});
```

Comment: you can use ajax or you can fetch all data from table at a time & keep in option filed as a data & on change you can display it

Comment: I have a blank form, with the required fields, what I want is to populate those fields once a client is chosen from the drop down list with the information stored on the DB.  So the information will constantly be different

Comment: you are using <option> in while loop... so when you click on option just get all option attribute using jquery & set it to form... all the time option fields attr will be different

Comment: ow you can use ajax & onchange execute call & pass id of the user & fetch data from table & set it to form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set data to option as

```
echo '<option data-address-"'.$address.'" value="'.$name.'_'.$surname.'">'.$name.' '.$surname.'</option>';
```

Also, update your query to get address along with name & surname.